# Does an omission of car model in a traffic ticket constitute grounds for dismissal?

Tags: united-states, missouri

I was recently pulled over on a charge of speeding. When filling out the ticket, the officer did not include my car's model or style, despite the model being clearly visible on the rear of the car. Is this omission important enough to warrant a dismissal of the case?

Comment: I don't know for sure, so just a comment. My hunch is that as long as there is some clear identification (e.g., license plate or VIN) and nothing *contradictory* then it still counts. My Dad once had a citation of some sort where he got notice by mail based on registration records. Knew it could not have actually happened. Drove to the police station. Officer took one look at the car and confirmed that while the license plate matched, other stuff (make, model color - I don't remember but something clear and obvious) did NOT match, case dismissed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You will still have to pay

A ticket can be ammended if the state so chooses (they can look up what color and model your car is).  The car is probably on video.  The officer can testify if they wrote your car info down somewhere else.  And if they identified you inside the car as the violator, the car's color hardly matters.

The idea that minor mistakes or omissions on tickets can get you off is a myth.

[From an actual lawyer](https://youtu.be/NXjX9Ut0Abc)